# Convert JPEG to PDF using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I did split PDF to JPEG images using PDFBox version 2.0.2. At first, I did just coding as sample like thatÖ

```
BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 300, ImageType.RGB);
```

And now, I want to convert this image to PDF, but the image DPI is so large.

I really want to reduce dpi. So I tried this, but it also didn't work:

```
PDImageXObject  pdImageXObject = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, bimg, 0.5f, 100);
```

How can I reduce DPI?

---

This is my source code:

```
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
            BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
            
            float width = bimg.getWidth() ;
            float height = bimg.getHeight();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
            
            doc.addPage(page);
            //PDStream stream = new PDStream(doc, in);
            
            PDImageXObject  pdImageXObject = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, bimg, 0.5f, 10);

            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            
            contentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, 0, 0);
            
            contentStream.close();
        }
    } finally { 
        System.out.println("ddd");
        doc.save(pdfPath);
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the bitmap image itself to a lower resolution? Or do you merely want to scale to fit on a page?

Comment: @mkl I think he wants to scale the image in a new PDF.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I want to change the bitmap image itself to a lower resolution, and make new PDF, because I tried to rendering new PDF to images, size too big each.

Comment: Why not just render it with 72dpi instead of 300? In that case 72 / 72 = 1. `BufferedImage image = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter, 72, ImageType.RGB);`

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems:

1) page size. It is not done in pixels but in page units. 1 unit = 1/72 inch. So your rectangle would be calculated like this:

```
PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width / 300 * 72, height / 300 * 72));
```

2) scale image. At 300dpi it must be scaled by 72/300 because the 1:1 is 72 dpi.

```
float scale = 72 / 300;
contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, pdImage.getWidth()*scale, pdImage.getHeight()*scale);
```

Btw using JPEGFactory is not a good idea, because some quality will be lost. Use LosslessFactory instead.

About your use of the dpi parameter of JPEGFactory - that is just metadata. It doesn't scale anything.

If you really want to "reduce dpi", then render the PDF at 72 dpi instead of 300, then you don't need the scaling when creating the new PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using the following:

```
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imgFile, doc);
PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, false, false);   
contents.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, PDRectangle.A4.getWidth(), PDRectangle.A4.getHeight());
```

Comment: Seeing no mention of image resolution: what problem *does* this solve?